# Node.JS / Linux / Weather / ActiveX / National Instruments

Tags: javascript, node.js, weather, activexobject, ubuntu-13.10

I'm developing an app using Node.JS, that receives SMS from different devices and reads the information, inserts into and updates the database and reads from it some data to convert it and show some markers in Google Maps API.

When I click on a marker, a modal window comes up with some of the data from that specific device.

The people I'm working for are asking me to use some ActiveX Objects called National Instruments Controllers, that will change their shape, direction and colors depending on the values of some of the marker's attributes.

Now, I'm developing this application in Ubuntu 13.10, so I can't really use ActiveX Objects, as far as I know. So does anyone know which controllers I can use that will work in Linux and will have their behavior affected by the marker's data?

Comment: If your targeting device is based on Activex then why don't you develop the stuff using windows environment. Is there any reason to sticking with Linux?

Comment: Yes, the people I'm developing the application for already have an app for that, but it's too slow. I'm developing it in node.js so the data that they see is closer to real-time.

Comment: Also, the application uses the serialport module, which I couldn't install in Windows after trying too many times, so I started developing in Linux, and they said they had no problem with it... In fact, they even got a pc and installed the same OS in it, so I could just upload the system to it when I'm done